# Latest record on 3 joined mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have been going round in circles now for a couple of days with this query and it's driving me nuts. I've found partial answers using max(date) and left joins but have as yet failed to achieve the right result so would be very grateful for any help.

I have 3 tables:-

> **inventory**
>   id 
>   lots of other fields...
>
> **sale_price**
>   id
>   date
>   *ticket_type_id
>   *inventory_id
>
> **ticket_type**
>   id
>   ticket_name

The sale_price table is updated with a date and new ticket type every time the sale price is changed. All I want to do is display:-

1. find the latest record in sale_price
2. display the inventory information related to this
3. display the ticket_name relating to this

The query that I have arrived at is:-

```
    $result = "
    SELECT DISTINCT inv.*, tt.ticket_name, MAX(sp.date) AS spdate 
               FROM sale_price sp 
               LEFT 
               JOIN ticket_type tt 
                 ON sp.ticket_type_id = tt.id
               JOIN inventory inv 
                 ON sp.inventory_id = inv.id                  
              GROUP 
                 BY sp.inventory_id
     ";
```

but it's clearly not working. I would be really grateful for any help you can give and (if it's not too much to as) a bit of detail on where I'm going wrong.

many thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to know the latest record of all then you could use following query:

```
SELECT
    s.ticket_type_id,
    s.inventory_id,
    t.ticket_name,
    i.lots of other fields  
FROM
    sale_price s
INNER JOIN
    inventory i
ON
    s.inventory_id = i.id
INNER JOIN
    ticket_type t
ON
    s.ticket_type_id = t.id;
WHERE
    s.date = (
        SELECT
            MAX(s1.date)        
        FROM
            sale_price s1
    )
```

If you need the latest record for every inventory item, then you've got to extend this query by using the equality of the inventory_id in the `WHERE` clause of the subselect:

```
SELECT
    s.ticket_type_id,
    s.inventory_id,
    t.ticket_name,
    i.lots of other fields  
FROM
    sale_price s
INNER JOIN
    inventory i
ON
    s.inventory_id = i.id
INNER JOIN
    ticket_type t
ON
    s.ticket_type_id = t.id;    
WHERE
    -- gives us the newest date per inventory_id
    s.date = (
        SELECT
            MAX(s1.date)
        FROM
            sale_price s1
        WHERE
            s.inventory_id = s1.inventory_id
    )
```

By the way, this is a correlated subquery and it could get slow.

Comment: First, Many thanks for your response - I wasn't aware that I could use a subquery in the WHERE clause, this opens up a whole new world of possibilities!

I tried the query that you provided but it's saying that the syntax is wrong. I'm sure it's something I did and I've been through it numerous times but can't see where the issue is - any idea's?

I will post in another comment because I'm about to run out of space...

Comment: Query Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN inventory i ON s.inventory_id = i.id INNER JOIN ticket_type t ON' at line 7


SELECT s.ticket_type_id, s.inventory_id, t.ticket_name, i.* FROM sale_price s WHERE s.date = (SELECT MAX(s1.date) FROM sale_price s2 WHERE s1.inventory_id = s2.inventory_id) INNER JOIN inventory i ON s.inventory_id = i.id INNER JOIN ticket_type t ON s.ticket_type_id = t.id

Comment: Maybe I need a bit of sleep. The `JOIN` clause got to be before the `WHERE` clause. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm now getting an error 'Unknown column 's1.date' in 'field list'

Comment: My oh my, it's getting worse. Some silly mistake in my second query. I used the alias names `s` and `s1`, so I should stick to it ... as it is now. Please try to understand the statement, not simply copy and paste.

Comment: It worked a treat. Words cannot express how grateful I am for your help! I've spent 2 days trying to figure this out - many many thanks indeed ;-)

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved. If you accept my answer then this question will be off the unanswered list.